# Rails can have several fields_for in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, nested-forms

Two models are belongs_to and has_many association. Such as:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_infos
end 

class UserInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
end
```

So, I build a form, I want to create a user account with several user_infos.
Could I do this in a form using nested form?

But what if I'm not sure how many :user_infos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. It depends on how many `user_infos` you want to create though. For example:

In your controller's `new` method:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  3.times{ @user.user_infos.build }
end
```

In your form:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= f.fields_for :user_infos do |uif| %>
     <%= uif.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will create 3 `user_infos` on form with text field name.

Comment: But I don't know how many user_infos should be added. I want to users to decide how many user infos they want to add.

Comment: @rocLv : This can be done via jQuery. Checkout these two railscasts [Nested Model Form part - 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [Nested Model Form part - 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) for more detail.

Comment: For Rails 4.2, I'm using ActionForm.